# Compound Interest Calculator in C is not working correctly; the arithmetic is not correct

Tags: c

I am a beginner in C, and I am trying to make a code that produces a compound interest for 10 years at interest rates of 5%, 6%, 7%, 8%, 9%, and 10%. The main issue with this program is that the values in the table will not be calculated correctly when the program runs.

I've tried to change the values of the variables to try and get them to work correctly, but the code still does not work the way it's supposed to. I made sure to at least initialize all of my variables.

What I did was use a for loop to add the rate to the amount every year. Since there are a total of 7 different rates, (0%, 5%, 6%, 7%, 8%, 9%, 10%), I used <=7.

```
>>//Language: C
//Compiler used: MSVS

#include <string>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996) 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float amt = 1000.00; //starting amount of money to be added over 10 years
    float initialrate = 0.05;
    float rate = 0;  //yearly interest rate
    float interest = 0;
    float initialinterest = 0 ;
    printf("%4s%21s\n", "Interest Rate", "Interest");
    printf("%4f%21f\n", initialrate, interest);

    for (float year = 1; year <= 7; ++year) { //get interest rates for 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1  (7 values)
        rate = 0.05 + 0.01, year;
        initialinterest = amt * initialrate + amt;
        interest = amt * rate + amt;




        while (++year <= 8) {
            printf("%f\n", "%f\n", initialrate, initialinterest);
            printf("%4f%21.2f\n", rate, interest);

        }//end loop 2

    }//end loop 1

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Interest Rate         Total interest
0.050000             0.000000
-0.000000
0.060000              1060.00
-0.000000
0.060000              1060.00
-0.000000
0.060000              1060.00
-0.000000
0.060000              1060.00
-0.000000
0.060000              1060.00
-0.000000
0.060000              1060.00
-0.000000
0.060000              1060.00
Press any key to continue . . .
```

However, it SHOULD look like this.

```
rate     total
0.05  $1628.89
0.06  $1790.85
0.07  $1967.15
0.08  $2158.92
0.09  $2367.36
0.1  $2593.74
```

Comment: What's this supposed to do? `rate = 0.05 + 0.01, year;`

Comment: Why only print the same numbers over and over inside the loop `while (++year <= 8) { ... }`, as nothing in them changes?

Comment: The code in the question is not the code that printed the output shown. Edit the question to show the exact code that produced the output.

Comment: Take this out: `while (++year <= 8)` or use a different name.

Comment: `rate = 0.05 + 0.01, year;` sets `rate` to `year`. The `0.05 + 0.01` has no effect.

Comment: `printf("%f\n", "%f\n", …` is incorrect; it attempts to use two format strings (and is how we know the code does not match the output). Use one format string.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings to catch things such as commas with no effect. Then use the debugger tutorial to set breakpoints and step through line by line to see if variables have the values they are supposed to at each step.

Comment: Start the program over. Make a loop that iterates interest rate from 5% to 10%. Inside that, make a loop that iterates for ten years. At the beginning of each year (before the loop), set the initial conditions (initial balance). Inside the loop, calculate the interest for that year and add it to the balance, then print the balance. Do not modify the interest rate or the year number inside the loops; just handle them in `for` statements. Redo the program this way, then ask a new question if you have further problems.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Will do. I'll let you know if anything comes up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You did right identifying the potential need for a nested loop.
However, making it you reset the inner calculation every year, hence the same result.

This line says nothing:

```
    printf("%4f%21f\n", initialrate, interest);
```

Also, the header **Total interest** is not valid, column shows the *balance* after 10 years, as **amt** is not interest but invested capital, it has to be deducted for the total in order to show *Total interest*, so your solution example is slightly wrong in this matter.

Here's one solution (leaving out "interest" in the header):

```
    float amt=1000.00; //starting amount of money
    float rate=0.05; //base rate scenario
    float total;
    printf("%4s%13s\n", "Interest Rate", "Total");
    for (int i=0, ;i<=5;i++){//rate scenario loop
        total=amt;
        for (int years = 0; years < 10;years++){//year loop
            total = total * (1+rate);
        }
        printf("%4.2f                 $\%.2f\n", rate, total);//prints the scenario outcome
        rate=rate+0.01;//scenario hike
    };
```

If you want to make use of the **math.h** lib that you are including, you can replace
this:

```
for (int years = 0; years < 10;years++){//year loop
            total = total * (1+rate);
        }
```

With

```
total = amt * (pow((1 + rate), 10));
```